# Cryptography signature scheme based on hardness of finding points on varieties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations, cryptography

Related to this question [Complexity of finding solutions of trapdoored polynomial](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445899/complexity-of-finding-solutions-of-trapdoored-polynomial).

I am trying to build signature scheme based on hardness
of finding points on varieties.

Let $K$ be field and $M=K[x_1,...x_n,y_1,...,y_m]$.

Let $V$ be the variety $f_1(x_i,y_i)=...f_k(x_i,y_i)=0$.

Alice constructs $V$ with some secret $S$ (trapdoor) such that
for all $y_i$, Alice can efficiently find $X_i$ such
that $F(X_i,y_i=Y_i)=0$. Correctness of the signature
of $Y_i$ is the vanishing of $F$.

So $V$ must satisfy the following properties:

1. For all $y_i$, Alice can find efficiently $X_i$ such
   that $F$ vanishes.
2. Without knowing the secret $S$, adversary can't efficiently find
   points on $V$ given $Y_i$.
3. (optional, feel free to skip) Given many points on $V$, resulting from valid signatures,
   adversary can't find the secret $S$ or otherwise forge signatures.

Potential approach is to start from "basis" and then obfuscate
them.

I am looking for hardness results and even high degree polynomial time
would be of interest.

> Q1 What complexity of hardness can we get for the above construction?

Comment: Here is my similar question, but I was more focused on a one-time-signature scheme. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435613/the-security-of-one-time-digital-signatures-from-a-solution-to-a-diophantine-equ

Comment: @JosephVanName For one time usage I suspect modification of the linked trapdoor question might work.

Comment: @JosephVanName I tried another trapdoor at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445974/hardness-of-solving-0-sum-i-1k-mathrmlinear-ix-1-x-nd-over-the-ra